# Extension methods with type name as `this` parameter, e.g. int?.TryParse(“32”)

Tags: c#, .net, clr, extension-methods

I want to write an extension method for nullable `int` so that I could write the code `int?.TryParse(“32”)` in a similar manner to writing `int.TryParse(“32”)`. The following method signature is not valid:

```
public static int? TryParse(this Type(int?), string input)
{
    ...
}
```

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static int? TryParse(this string input) {
  int i;
  return int.TryParse(input, out i) ? i : (int?)null;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
var i = yourString.TryParse();
```

I think you may want to define a generic method like this:

```
public static T? TryParse<T>(this string input) where T : struct {
   T i = default(T);                        
   object[] args = new object[] { input, i };
   var tryParse = typeof(T).GetMethod("TryParse", 
                             new[] { typeof(string), typeof(T).MakeByRefType() });
   if(tryParse != null){
       var r = (bool) tryParse.Invoke(null, args);            
       return r ? (T) args[1] : (T?)null;
   }
   return (T?)null;
}
//Usage
double? d = yourString.TryParse<double>();
int? i = yourString.TryParse<int>();
```

Using the generic method above is very convenient but the performance may be reduced a little due to using reflection. If you just want some `TryParse` methods for some types `int`, `double`, ... You should define particular method for each one, named them differently like `TryParseInt`, `TryParseDouble`, `TryParseDecimal`, ... and apply the similar code to the first code snippet I posted above.

Comment: What if i will want to have for `double?` and `long?` as well?

Comment: @XyiTebe make other methods for them

Comment: Thank you for editing @urs, I've just noticed about the error right after your edit.

Comment: Which type will have `var k = "32".TryParse()` if I have such `TryParse` both for `int?` and `long?` - compiler will complain since methods in C# are not overloaded on return value.

Comment: @XyiTebe if you want to use multi `TryParse`, you should define it as `generic`, see my update.

Comment: That should work fine although it is a bit more clumsy compare to `int?.TryParse(“32”)` - the idea was to imitate `int.TryParse(“32”)` syntaxis.

Comment: @XyiTebe unless you define more extension methods for each `int`, `double` such as `TryParseInt`, `TryParseDouble`... otherwise using generic as what I posted is better.

Comment: Your generic version could be applied to any struct that has `TryParse` - even better than I wanted. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods look like instance methods, but are in fact static methods. When you define an extension method, you can extend instances of a class with a new method, but you cannot extend the class itself with a new static method.